# Dojo - fix up inline html fragment

Tags: dojo

I'm downloading an html fragment and placing in a DIV using xhrGet/dojo.place. This works very well except that the fragment contains Dojo widgets and these are not being created.

How do I fix up the placed HTML so that the widgets get created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `dojo.parser.parse()` on the div.

```
myDiv.innerHTML = "Content from xhr <input dojoType='dijit.form.TextBox' />";
dojo.parser.parse(myDiv);
```

Note that you need to `dojo.require` the widget classes used in the fragment.